# cannot ping 8.8.8.8 with tailscale started

Tags: mac-osx, cloudflare, tailscale

We have been using tailscale for several years now without too many issues.

I have a user whose device cannot ping 8.8.8.8 when tailscale is started. There are no tailscale exit nodes involved and the tailscale client configuration appears identical (default config, running tailscale v1.148.1 on OSX). 8.8.8.8 can be pinged once Tailscale is switched off.

A complicating factor might be the fact that this device also has Cloudflare Warp installed but in this instance CloudFlare Warp has been disabled (with an override code) and other devices do not have this problem when CloudFlare Warp is disabled in this way.

I have compared the route tables of a working and non-working devices and they appear similar in most respects. There are some (I think) minor differences in the Flags associated with the default route which I can't explain

not-working:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            link#21            UCSg            utun3       
default            10.133.10.1        UGScIg            en0
```

working:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags           Netif Expire
default            10.133.10.1        UGScg             en0       
default            link#18            UCSIg           utun3
```

I will amend my question with details of the ifconfig output when I have the output from the non-working device.

Comment: Why do you need to ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Two reasons
 
- like many organisations we use the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 as our primary DNS
- pinging this well known IP address is one way to verify basic IP connectivity

Comment: On the not working machine, it seems like the default route with highest priority is utun3 (tailscale tunnel). If Exit Node is not enabled, the default gateway with highest priority should be your local router. Enabling an Exit Node is a sure-fire way to get that route to appear first, so that's a little suspicious. If a reboot, toggle, update don't fix it, check the order of network services on the mac to ensure that they appear in the right order—and if not, fix the order: `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` will list their order.

Comment: Do you have any Exit Nodes on your tailnet? If so you could update the ACL to allow this user's traffic to `autogroup:internet:*` and see if they can ping 8.8.8.8. If so, their network settings are stuck using an Exit Node.